# what am i missing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

here is my task:

Create  a   view    FinancialStatus that    shows,  for each    person that has an
account,    the PID and pName   of  the person, and the total   amount  they    have
on  their   accounts    minus   all unpaid  bills   that    are past    due date.

here are my tabels:

```
 CREATE TABLE People (
PID INT, 
pName VARCHAR(50),
pGender CHAR(1),
pHeight FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (PID)
);

CREATE TABLE Accounts (
AID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, -- IDENTITY for MS-SQL
PID INT,
aDate DATE,
aBalance INT,
aOver INT,
PRIMARY KEY (AID),
FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES People(PID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bills (
BID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, -- IDENTITY for MS-SQL
PID INT,
bDueDate DATE NOT NULL,
bAmount INT,
bIsPaid BIT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BID),
FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES People(PID)
);
```

here are my querys so far:

```
create view debts as
select b.bispaid, p.pid, p.pname, sum(b.bamount) as bamount2
from bills b, people p
where p.pid = b.pid
AND b.bDueDate < curdate()
AND b.bispaid = 0
group by p.pid;

CREATE VIEW totalbal AS
    SELECT P.PID, P.pName, SUM(A.aBalance) as bal
    FROM People P, Accounts A
    WHERE P.PID = A.PID
    GROUP BY P.PID;

create view FinancialStatus as
select p.pid, p.pName, (t.bal - d.bamount2) as remains
from totalbal t, debts d, people p
where p.pid = d.pid
AND p.pid = t.pid;
-- group by p.pid;

select * from   FinancialStatus;
```

and here is what is wrong:

the FinancialStatus view returns the right table except when the person have no bills that is past duedate, for example:

John: account balance is 1000$, and his bills past duedate are 400$ then the FinancialStatus view returns the right results which are:

```
...
4   Doe    346$
5   John    600$
6   Boe     1900$
...
```

here is when it goes wrong:

John: account balance is 1000$ an no bills past duedate

```
 ...
    4   Doe    346$
                        <-here is supposed to be : 5    John    1000$
    6   Boe    1900$
    ...
```

what am i missing?? :)

Comment: Are you sure pid 5 is present in debts, totalbal and people?

Comment: You need to use a Left Outer Join.  all your queries are inner joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do a left join, because the `debts` view has no records for John.

```
create view FinancialStatus as
select p.pid, p.pName, (t.bal - IFNULL(d.bamount2, 0)) as remains
from totalbal t
inner join people p on p.pid = t.pid
left join debts d on p.pid = d.pid
```

*Note I have no experience with MySql, so I'm not sure the syntax is 100% accurate.*